# How can I get multiple appendices to be correctly labeled A, B, C

Tags: appendices

I'm using

```
%\documentclass[twocolumn,showpacs,preprintnumbers,amsmath,amssymb]{revtex4}
\documentclass[preprint,showpacs,preprintnumbers,amsmath,amssymb]{revtex4}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\numberthis{\addtocounter{equation}{1}\tag{\theequation}}

%\documentclass[preprint,aps]{revtex4}
%\documentclass[preprint,aps,draft]{revtex4}
%\documentclass[prb]{revtex4}% Physical Review B

\usepackage{graphicx}% Include figure files
\usepackage{dcolumn}% Align table columns on decimal point
\usepackage{bm}% bold math
\usepackage{amsmath}
```

I have three appendices that are all being labeled as "A", rather than "A", "B" "C".

I tried (after consulting the stack exchange) using `"\begin{appendices}...\end{appendices}"` and also just using
`"\begin{appendix}...\end{appendix}"` once instead of three times.

They all still get labeled as "Appendix A".

Comment: for making it easier to help, you should create a complete minimal working example of the current status of your work. In a book class, adding chapters in the appendix creates a new letter A, B, .. for each chapter: like `\appendix
\chapter{First Appendix}
  \section{Section One}
  \section{Section Two}
\chapter{Second Appendix}
  \section{Section One}
  \section{Section Two}`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the command `\appendix` instead of `\begin{appendix}...\end{appendix}`. Then follow the command with the text of your appendices. All following `\section` commands will be labeled with capital letters instead of numbers.

I included a couple of sections and a TOC in my MWE so that you can see the numbering styles change from the main document vs. the appendix. Hope that's what you're looking for!

(Note: remember to include a complete [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) when you post a question.)

```
    \documentclass[preprint,showpacs,preprintnumbers,amsmath,amssymb]{revtex4}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \newcommand\numberthis{\addtocounter{equation}{1}\tag{\theequation}}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{dcolumn}
    \usepackage{bm}
    \usepackage{amsmath} 
    
    \begin{document}
    
    \tableofcontents
    
    \section{Section One}
    Text for section one.
    
    \subsection{Subsection One}
    Text for subsection one.
    
    \appendix
    
    \section{First Appendix}
    Text for appendix one.
    \subsection{First Appendix Subsection}
    
    \section{Second Appendix}
    Text for appendix two.
    \end{document}
```

My result looks like this:
[image]

Comment: this saved my 1-2 days of searching